# Is it possible to play 2 video file simultaneously in the same view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, iad

Is it possible to play 2 video files simultaneously in the same view?

I want to do have them both playing over half the screen, a little like this:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|                   |
|                   |
|       VIDEO       |
|                   |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
|                   |
|                   |
|      VIDEO        | 
|                   |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

apple's document said:

Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.

so,you know...

Comment: @dinosaur: So wat should I do if I want to play animation with media file ?

Comment: animation with media file?  what effect you want ? can you give me same Description?

Comment: I want to play an audio file in first half view and in second half view   I want to play some animation that will be a video. Actually I am playing audio file with MPMoviePlayerController because while playing with AVAudioPlayer I m not getting the controls of player. So the theme is that I m playing an audio as a media file and also want to play another media file for animation. In this way here is 2 media file to play simultaneously.

Comment: when you play movie,other audio can not playback.

Comment: It's my pleasure.hope this can help you.

Answer (score 6):

Play 2 video's at a time is possible..

**STEPS:**

1.create 2 instance of MPMoviePlayer

2.set frame for 2 player by using CGRectMake

3.Add 2 players to the view(self.view)

I hope above steps are helpful for u.

**setting frame for player only supported in iOS 3.2 and above versions.**

Let me know you have any doubt.

**Sample Code:**

```
player1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240);
[self.view addSubview:player1.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:player1];
[player1 play];
player2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 241, 320, 220);
[self.view addSubview:player2.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:player2];
[player2 play];
```

Comment: Clear up your grammar and add some code and I'm sure you'll get some upvotes.

Comment: Thanks, but here what is player in code [self.view addSubview:player.view];

Comment: @Archana Chaurasia:[self.view addSubview:player.view]; and [self.view addSubview:player2.view]; for player1 and player2

Comment: @iphonecool: exactly same I am doing but it shows only last player means its overlapping the previous player although I set frame area.

Comment: @Archana Chaurasia:please wait.I will check it and tell you.

Comment: In iOS 5.0.1 on the iPad 2 it is _not_ possible. It stops the first player if the second is started.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AVPlayer to play two video simultaneously seeting frame of Layer you can get the required frame Please follow following [link](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66).