# Is it possible to display 2 video on 2 different surface view within an android activity?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

I've done some research on display 2 different videos on 2 different surface view, but didn't manage to find any.

Is this possible in android?

I'm want to use android MediaPlayer to stream the videos.

Found something similar but is in iphone. [Is it possible to play 2 video file simultaneously in the same view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076044/is-it-possible-to-play-2-video-file-simultaneously-in-the-same-view)

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).Though it will be better in tablet.Look it out if it can work in your case.Here example is different but the concept is same. :)

Comment: Hi Android Power, thanks for the tips, will try out your input. And hopefully i'm able to figure out. Thank you so much!

Comment: @chin Is it possible to play 2 webrtc streams simultaneously in a single Activity via a streaming connection in Android??